# Resultados duplicados ao realizar busca com o POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

Estou realizando uma busca no banco de dados onde eu realizo alguns JOIN em tabelas diferentes. No SQL que inseir abaixo eu faço um join com a tabela produto_categoria_compativel onde o id do produto deve estar presente nela para retornar com quais categorias ele é compatível. Nessa tabela produto_categoria_compativel tem apenas o id do produto e o id da categoria. Quando eu executo esse SQL ele me retorna a listagem dos produtos mas ele está duplicando os registros listados. Eu tentei usar o group by passando o id do produto mas ele retorna erro dizendo que deve ser passado outro parâmetro no group by e conforme eu vou adicionando os parâmetros no group by ele continua retornando o mesmo erro. Segue abaixo o SQL e os exemplos de erro

```
SELECT produto.id,
   produto.nome,
   produto.valor,
   loja.id,
   loja.nome,
   loja.situacao,
   categoria.id,
   categoria.id_pai,
   categoria.nome,
   categoria.nome_pai,
FROM produto_derivacao
JOIN produto ON produto.id = produto_derivacao.produto_id
JOIN loja ON loja.id = produto.loja_id
JOIN categoria ON categoria.id = produto.categoria_id
JOIN produto_categoria_compativel ON produto.id = produto_categoria.produto_id
GROUP BY produto.id
```

**Exemplos de erros:**

```
coluna "loja.id" deve aparecer na cláusula GROUP BY ou ser utilizada em uma função de agregação
coluna "categoria.id" deve aparecer na cláusula GROUP BY ou ser utilizada em uma função de agregação
coluna "categoria.id_pai" deve aparecer na cláusula GROUP BY ou ser utilizada em uma função de agregação
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    produto_id,
    nome,
    valor,
    loja_id,
    nome,
    situacao,
    categoria_id,
    id_pai,
    nome,
    nome_pai
from (
    select distinct
        produto.id as produto_id,
        produto.nome,
        produto.valor,
        loja.id as loja_id,
        loja.nome,
        loja.situacao,
        categoria.id as categoria_id,
        categoria.id_pai,
        categoria.nome,
        categoria.nome_pai,
        COLUNA_PARA_ORDENACAO
    from
        produto_derivacao
        join
        produto on produto.id = produto_derivacao.produto_id
        join
        loja on loja.id = produto.loja_id
        join
        categoria on categoria.id = produto.categoria_id
        join
        produto_categoria_compativel on produto.id = produto_categoria.produto_id
) s
order by COLUNA_PARA_ORDENACAO
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa utilizar o `group by`, pois não há nenhuma função de agregação na consulta.

Utilize o *distinct* para remover os itens duplicados e mude os *joins* para *left* ou *right* dependendo da posição da tabela.

Segue abaixo o SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (produto.id),
   produto.nome,
   produto.valor,
   loja.id,
   loja.nome,
   loja.situacao,
   categoria.id,
   categoria.id_pai,
   categoria.nome,
   categoria.nome_pai,
FROM produto_derivacao
RIGH JOIN produto ON produto.id = produto_derivacao.produto_id
LEFT JOIN loja ON loja.id = produto.loja_id
JOIN categoria ON categoria.id = produto.categoria_id
LEFT JOIN produto_categoria_compativel ON produto.id = produto_categoria.produto_id
```

Comment: Herivelton Paiva, se usar o distinct ele da pau no order by "Erro: para SELECT DISTINCT, expressões ORDER BY devem aparecer na lista de seleção"

Comment: Apenas adicione a mesma coisa que tem no seu order by na clausula select.